# PowerPivot Relationship - Error says both columns must contain only unique values

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I am stumped by this error that PowerPivot gives me when I create a relationship between product table where item_id is unique and sales table which has item_id. It says both columns must have unique values!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities here. Firstly, it's possible you are trying to set up your relationships in the wrong direction.

For instance, this works fine:

[image]

...but swapping the Table and Related Table around gives you the error message you are getting:

[image]

The second possibility is that there are in fact duplicates in your Product Table item_id column.  The easiest way to double check this is to make a PivotTable out of the product table, drag the item_id field into it as both a rowfield and a data field, change the aggregation to Count, and then set a Values filter to display items **greater than** 1. (Note that in the below screenshot which is taken from the book I'm working on, the values filter is set to display items **equal to** 1. You'll need to change that).

[image]

Comment: If you see the image I attached, it says both columns must have unique values.

Comment: It says that even if just one Table has duplicates. It's a poorly worded message. So either your product table does in fact have duplicates (and you can check that using the method I've outlined above); or you are trying to set up the relationship in the wrong direction (and I've updated my answer to demonstrate this).

Comment: I dont think it is poorly worded. It says, "at least" one of the columns contains duplicates. And it reiterates that by saying that "both columns" must have unique values. 
I can confirm to you that I do have one column with unique values.

Comment: I will check again if I have the file which threw this error to see if I was setting it up in the wrong direction.

Comment: It gives me the same error no matter what direction the relationship is set.

Answer (score 0):

Just run into this issue and it works now. In the process I have learnt:

- I have a table with duplicated values and the other with unique values and I can set the relationship (nly now after the steps I explain below, it did not work before)
- The table with unique values have to be in the right side of the relationship (the engine needs to find at most one record starting from the foreign key)
- The table with unique values in my case was defeined as a Table in Excel and had 4 empty rows. For the engine these 4 empty rows are seen as duplicated values so the relationship would not work. You need to delete empty rows in your table
- After deleting empty rows it would still not work (funny that bit and maybe my memory fails now that I am writing). It happens that my table with unique values is a table that belongs to the Excel file but the other one was only a connector with the data outside the Ecxcel file. I had to refresh all data in the file (ie. read the external tables pointed by the connectors) for the relation set up to work.

Comment: Its been a while and I don't have the file now to check if it had blank rows in either of the tables but that could well be the reason.